# Laravel nested resource retrieve model by slug instead of id

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a Laravel 8 project, it's being used as an API for a frontend. My API contains **Brands** and **Forms**, a brand is created by a user and a brand can have a form.

My brand schema contains a `slug` column, it's this column that's present in my front-end URLs, the `slug` column is unique, e.g:

- /account/brands/my-brand/forms/
- /account/brands/my-brand/forms/create/

A form has a `brand_id` column, this is later used as part of Laralve's `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationship for automatic joining since it's easier this way and means I don't have to have an ugly URL.

The trouble I'm having is when I want to show the user a list of their forms for the brand they're on I don't have access to the `brand_id` in the request, only the `slug` as this is part of the URL, whereas to retrieve my forms I need the `brand_id`.

How could I easily (without having another function) obtain this whilst still ensuring my relationships in my model work correctly?

**Retrieving forms for a brand that belong to a user**

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index($brand)
{
    // $brand -> this is the slug, unsure how to utilise this on the joined brand
    $forms = Form::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('brand')->get();

    return response()->json([
        'forms' => $forms
    ], 200);
}
```

My `Brand` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Brand extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'brands';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'uuid',
        'brand',
        'url',
        'telephone',
        'link_terms',
        'link_privacy',
        'seo_description',
        'base64_logo',
        'base64_favicon',
        'text_marketing',
        'text_promos',
        'text_broker',
        'text_footer_1',
        'text_footer_2',
        'text_credit_disclaimer',
        'analytics_internal_affiliate'
    ];

    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = [
        'form'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the form associated with the user.
     */
    public function form()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Form::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the brand that owns the comment.
     */
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

My `Form` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Form extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'forms';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'loan_amount',
        'loan_min_amount',
        'loan_max_amount',
        'loan_term',
        'loan_min_term',
        'loan_max_term'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the brand that owns the comment.
     */
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The path of least resistance would be to harness the `whereRelationship()` method on your query.

I believe that would look like this:

```
 $forms = Form::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->whereRelationship('brand', '=', $brand)
->with('brand')
->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

An alternative which would be more work to set up but would likely make your life easier long term would be to use route model binding.  https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding

You can ask Laravel's IoC container to resolve the full record for you by typehinting it and naming the variable correctly in the method signature.

Since you are using a column other than `id` to identify it, you need to inform Laravel of this. There are a couple of different ways to do this, discussed at https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name

Then, you can ask Laravel's IoC container to build an instance of the model by searching in the database for you right in the method signature. You simply need to typehint the parameter and ensure it's name matches that in the route definition.